# TestNG test skips while executing it inside servlet

Tags: java, servlets, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to Execute TestNG test inside servlet with the help of "[TestListenerAdapter](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/TestListenerAdapter.html)" and "[TestNG](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/TestNG.html)" my code snippet is like this:

```
TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
TestNG testng = new TestNG();
testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] {src.scriptDemo.LoginTest.class});
testng.addListener(tla);
testng.run();
```

So, When i am executing this code snippet inside a Java Program the test name "LoginTest" is executing successfully (i.e. test starts, browsers opens and whole test executes).
But when the same code runs inside a Servlet it gives:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  Command line suite


===============================================
Command line suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================
```

It seems like test starts to execute but skipped. I don't know the reason behind this.

PS: I debug my code and found that, It skips test due to FirefoxDriver() in the LoginTest selenium script file. Code of LoginTest.java is:

```
package src.scriptDemo;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class LoginTest {

    WebDriver driver;
    String baseUrl;
    @BeforeTest
    public void setupSelenium() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(true);
        baseUrl = "https://example.com/login";
        System.out.println("1:");
    }

    @Test
    public void testCsrLogin() {
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        System.out.println("2:");
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("blah");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("blah");
        driver.findElement(By.className("btn-primary")).click();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void closeSelenium() {
            System.out.println("3:");
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
    }
}
```

But while executing again by commenting FirefoxDriver(), the test runs without any problem and gives output

```
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
```

Can anyone suggest whats going on here and how to solve it, 
Please let me know if more description is required.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: In which container you deployed the code and where it is running ? locally or remotely ?

Comment: Hey Karthikeyan, I am deploying it locally.

Comment: @HimanilGupta i have similar issue, is above issue resolved now ? can you explain with answer, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you run them inside a container, the should make use of selenium grid.(i.e, you have to create a RemoteWebDriver instance rather your Browser Specific instance).To get started with selenium grid please visit [this link](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC4QFjAB&url=http://theautomationtester.wordpress.com/category/selenium-webdriver-2/&ei=z6seU4PkHcyS1AWu44DwCw&usg=AFQjCNGASqSDOhCJ2mcz-10RPIW6kmRbtw&bvm=bv.62788935,d.d2k). Make sure the Selenium and grid dependency are added and packaged in your war.

Comment: Thanks for answering, My main motto here is to execute selenium script from UI(i.e. select script and click on run button), thats why I am using servlets which handles request and response like [TestNGEE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/testngee/) rather than executing it on remote machines through Grid.

Comment: You have to understand [this](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol) to know more how selenium scripts are communicating with browsers. If are placing your web driver scripts inside a container, then even if you are running on a single machine, locally you need to use grid. Unless it is not possible. If you have any options please let the community know !